# How to get the name from an email address with an additional partition using python

Tags: python

I am trying to separate the name from the domain name in python. I have gotten fairly close, however the output doesn't look quite right. This is what I have done thus far:

```
def get_name(email_list):
   x = []
   for name in email_list:
      y, _, _ = name.partition("@")
      split_name = y.split('_')
      x.append(split_name)
   return(x)
```

When I run this with this example of an input:

```py
get_name(["arthur_blake@gmail.com", "bob_dylan@gmail.com"])
```

I get the following output:

```py
[['arthur', 'blake'], ['bob', 'dylan']]
```

I want the output to look like so:

```py
['Arthur Blake', 'Bob Dylan']
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.capitalize` to convert first letter to uppercase and `str.join` to convert a list of words into a single string.

```
def get_name(email_list):
   x = []
   for name in email_list:
      y, _, _ = name.partition("@")
      split_name = y.split('_')
      x.append(" ".join([n.capitalize() for n in split_name]))
   return(x)

print(get_name(["arthur_blake@gmail.com", "bob_dylan@gmail.com"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str.replace` and `str.title` to keep the name as one string and capitalize it like you want:

```py
def get_name(email_list):
   x = []
   for name in email_list:
      y, _, _ = name.partition("@")
      full_name = y.replace('_', ' ')
      titled_name = full_name.title()
      x.append(titled_name)
   return(x)
```

The line `y.replace('_', ' ')` replaces all instances of `_` with a space, turning `arthur_blake` into `arthur blake`.
The statement `split_name.title()` capitalizes the first letter of each word, turning `arthur blake` into `Arthur Blake`

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution, as quasi one-liner (I do like [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)):

```py
mails = ['joe_doe@gmail.com', 'peter_parker@mail.com']

def get_name(email_list):
  return [' '.join(m.split('@')[0].split('_')).title() for m in email_list]

print(get_name(mails))
```